# OS X 10.11 Disk Utility, encrypted dmg password and keychain

Tags: macos, disk-utility, keychain, encryption, dmg

In previous versions of Disk Utility there were checkboxes whether to store the password in the keychain or not while creating an encrypted dmg image. Now there are less options.

Does the new version of Disk Utility safe the password in the keychain by default when an encrypted dmg volumes is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Disk Utility (in El Capitan) you won't be asked at all to save the password to a keychain while creating the encrypted dmg. But after unmounting and reopening the newly created encrypted dmg you will be asked to enter the password and the option to save it to the keychain will be shown:

[image: password encrypted dmg]

Comment: Does that mean that Disk Utility doesn't save passwords to keychain by default?

Comment: @gikel3888 You are right - by default it won't be saved to the keychain!